# how to save a report in the local system in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracleforms, oraclereports

how to save a report in the local system in Oracle Forms 12c. Like in Forms 6i, we are using the run_product() procedure to save a report in the local system

```
pl_id := create_parameter_list('us00300p');
    add_parameter(pl_id,'paramform',text_parameter,'no');
    add_parameter(pl_id,'xiposl',text_parameter,sl_no); 
    and so on
```

run_product(reports,filepath&filename,synchronous,runtime,filesystem,pl_id,null);

how to replace this procedure in Forms 12c insead of using to save file in the local system.This is Forms 6i code how to write like this in Forms 12c

select ora_12c,report_server,rep_str into m_12c,vc_reportserver,mrep_str from single_row;
if m_12c = 1 then

```
    v_report_id := find_report_object('rat');
    
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE,SYNCHRONOUS);
 
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESTYPE,CACHE);
    
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id, REPORT_DESFORMAT,'pdf');

    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_SERVER,vc_reportserver);

    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,report_filename,Filepath&FileName);
    
    v_ReportServerJob := run_report_object(report_id,pl_id);

    vjob_id := substr(ReportServerJob,instr(ReportServerJob,'_',-1)+1);

    vc_rep_status := REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(ReportServerJob);
    
    IF  vc_rep_status = 'FINISHED' THEN
    
      --WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT (serverURL,Servername,Jobid,'_blank');
           How to replace this save a report in the local system without opening browser
```

Comment: In Oracle 6i form builder we are using run product () procedure to save a report as pdf in the local system. Like this I have to do in Oracle 12c form builder but I don't know how to do?

Comment: I updated your categories for you. This is a question for Forms, not for Oracle (the database).

Comment: I explained how to do this in the Oracle Forms Forum in this thread;   https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-save-a-report-in-the-local-system-in-oracle-12c-9686

Answer (score 0):

Here, the answer is there please check it.

```
select ora_12c,report_server,rep_str into m_12c,vc_reportserver,mrep_str from table_name;
```

```
if m_12c = 1 then
    v_report_id := find_report_object('rat');

     SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE,SYNCHRONOUS);
     SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESTYPE,CACHE);
     SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id, REPORT_DESFORMAT,'pdf');
     SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_SERVER,vc_reportserver);
     SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,report_filename,Filepath&FileName);
     v_ReportServerJob := run_report_object(report_id,pl_id);
     vjob_id := substr(ReportServerJob,instr(ReportServerJob,'_',-1)+1);
     vc_rep_status := REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(ReportServerJob);
       
IF  vc_rep_status = 'FINISHED' THEN
      --> Save a report in the local system without opening the browser <--
      COPY_REPORT_OBJECT_OUTPUT(v_ReportServerJob,'c:\mylocaldir\file.pdf');
    --&* This is the answer to my question. Hope, it would be helpful for someone *&--
end if;
```